Is there a way to cache this rendered View?
These Articles when emailed via Simplenews have a list of recent posts which we derive from a block view.
Seemingly this block / view is rendered for every outgoing email message and I believe that this is having undesirable side effects.
Is there some way I can cache the view's output once per "send" and empty the cache or replace the cached view on the next simplenews "send"?
Code in the theme:
function pellucid_olivero_preprocess_node__article__email_html(&$variables) {
  $relatedArticles = views_embed_view('frontpage_news_items', 'block_2');
  $variables['related_articles'] = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($relatedArticles);
}


Could this be equivalent to this feature request? https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews/issues/3081703

Is this about Simplenews or render caching in general? In what way are the articles related? Is the block view used in other places and is the context the same as in the mail? If in doubt create a separate view display for the embedded view. After you have checked that there are no unwanted dependencies you can cache the View by adding cache keys. BTW you don't have to render(), you can nest unrendered build arrays.

Honestly not sure I can answer your questions but you’ve given me a couple of avenues of research. Very useful. Thanks  @4uk4
